# How to forced textinput event in textbox WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, textbox

I have a WPF application that runs multiple threads, in one of the threads this application use Application.DoEvent(), because is migrated from windows.forms project. Also this application opens a WPF window from a different project. Everything looks fine, however, when I enter text into a text box in the other project's window, the text box does not work correctly. Sometimes when I press a key, the character is not displayed in the text box. I put console.WriteLine in the textInput and keyUp events and noticed that the keyUp event always fires, however the textInput does not always fire. Any suggestions on how to force the textInput event to fire?

I need the text box to work fine. I tried to replace the textbox text from the keyUp event, however, e.Key only gives me the code of the key pressed, but I am unable to get the specific character which includes alphanumeric characters and special characters.

Here is part of my code:

```
private void TxtUsuario_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isText = false;
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                if (txtContrasena.Password == "")
                    txtContrasena.Focus();
                else
                    BtnAceptar_Click(null, null);
            }
            else
            {
                string key = e.Key.ToString();
                bool isCapsLockOn = (Keyboard.GetKeyStates(Key.CapsLock) & KeyStates.Toggled) == KeyStates.Toggled;
                bool isShiftKeyPressed = (Keyboard.Modifiers & ModifierKeys.Shift) == ModifierKeys.Shift;

                if (!isCapsLockOn && !isShiftKeyPressed)
                    key = key.ToLower();

                isText = (e.Key >= Key.A && e.Key <= Key.Z) || (e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9)
                                || e.Key == Key.OemQuestion || e.Key == Key.OemQuotes || e.Key == Key.OemPlus || e.Key == Key.OemOpenBrackets || e.Key == Key.OemCloseBrackets || e.Key == Key.OemMinus
                                 || e.Key == Key.DeadCharProcessed || e.Key == Key.Oem1 || e.Key == Key.Oem7 || e.Key == Key.OemPeriod || e.Key == Key.OemComma || e.Key == Key.OemMinus
                                  || e.Key == Key.Add || e.Key == Key.Divide || e.Key == Key.Multiply || e.Key == Key.Subtract || e.Key == Key.Oem102 || e.Key == Key.Decimal;

                if (isText)
                {
                    if ((e.Key >= Key.D0 && e.Key <= Key.D9) || (e.Key >= Key.NumPad0 && e.Key <= Key.NumPad9))
                        key = key.Replace("d", "");

                    if (((TextBox)sender).Tag != null && ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length < ((TextBox)sender).Tag.ToString().Length)
                        ((TextBox)sender).Tag = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
                    else
                        ((TextBox)sender).Tag = ((TextBox)sender).Tag + key;

                    ((TextBox)sender).Text = ((TextBox)sender).Tag.ToString();
                }
                else if (key != "leftshift" && key != "rightshift")
                {
                    ((TextBox)sender).Tag = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
                }

                ((TextBox)sender).CaretIndex = ((TextBox)sender).Text.Length;
            }
        }
```

This event always fires, but the text is entered incomplete in the text box.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: A Windows Forms app should never ever ever use `Application.DoEvents()` so you shouldn't either. It's only there for backward compatibility with VB6! Using it is a quick way for your app to descend into hell.

Comment: The answer to your question is to not use multiple threads that work on the UI and to not use `DoEvents`.

Comment: Thank you @Enigmativity for your comments. Now I understand the legacy code of my application. I simply removed all the Application.DoEvent invocations and the problem was resolved. Thank you very much again

Comment: @GuillermoSanper - Why was the `Application.DoEvents()` in there in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure. This application was developed in vb in 2006, a few years later the original developers migrated it to vb.net, then we migrated almost all the code to C# Windows Forms, last year we started changed it the UI from Windows Forms to WPF.
Currently the main thread is still in vb.net with the UI in a new project in C# WPF, the DoEvents invocation exists since the original developer made the application.
This app is very complex, installed with over 3,000 clients and integrating with multiple devices, so unfortunately we can't simply build it from scratch.

Comment: @GuillermoSanper - It made sense it was there for VB6. But it should have been the first thing ripped out in any .NET app. Do you understand what it does?

Comment: Not really. My understanding was that it was used to allow the UI to work while a loop works on the backend.

Comment: @GuillermoSanper - Back when that was the only way to make that work. BackgroundWorker and threads in .NET negate the need.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot @Enigmativity